# Should we have a tag for lines?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags

It has been asked several times on the site how to make lines from to-from different point coordinates. Should we include a tag for line or something else specific? We have a tag for linestring, would that suffice?

[Here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/5275/draw-lines-from-points) is the recent question.

Here are two other questions that are very similar, but each has entirely different tags.

- [script-for-automated-line-drawing-procedure-for-set-of-start-and-end-points](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/2641/script-for-automated-line-drawing-procedure-for-set-of-start-and-end-points)
- [arcgis-create-a-line-layer-from-a-point-layer-and-csv-data-file](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/3730/arcgis-create-a-line-layer-from-a-point-layer-and-csv-data-file)

Any more general advice about how we should make/organize tags I think would be appropriate to state here as well.

Comment: After brief discussion in the GIS Chat Room I have merged [tag:polyline] into [tag:line].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A search for "line" turns up over 300 threads (over 20% of all the questions)!

Some of these are tagged with the near-useless "geometry".  Obviously "polyline" could replace "geometry" and provide useful additional information.

As an experiment I reviewed the latest 90 threads.  About half the time "line" refers to a non-polyline, such as a command line.  I found about 15 that focused on *creating* a new polyline of some sort.  To these I added a new tag, "polyline-creation".  I also created a similar tag "polygon-creation" for questions asking about how to create polygons of some sort (such as by closing a set of polylines).

Extrapolating from this suggests about 50 questions should be tagged with "polyline-creation".

Would it help to further refine these tags and have a collection that includes, say, "polyline-editing" and "polyline-selection"?

Comment: I would like to see the addition as suggested in your last two lines, which also would suggest that polygon-creation etc could also be added to tags.

Answer (score 1):

Nowadays, tags [line](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/line) (<s>x190</s> 451) and [polyline](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/polyline) (<s>x151</s> 514) are synonyms.

Their currently excerpts are also synonyms:

> Line:
>
> A set of ordered co-ordinates that represent the shape of geographic features too narrow to be displayed as an area at the given scale (contours, street centre lines, or streams), or linear features with no area (county boundary lines)

---

> Polyline:
>
> A digital map feature that represents a place or thing that has length but not area at a given scale. A polyline feature may have one or more parts.

Therefore, I suggest the following:

1. Decide which tag should be the master (which I think it could be any of them, because they are almost 50/50 picked).
2. Make them synonyms.
3. Merge.

Comment: +1 Useful links to reference here could be http://forums.esri.com/Thread.asp?c=93&f=982&t=250471#766452 and http://www.zwsoft.com/CAD-Support/line-and-polyline-in-autocad.html - I am not sure that I would use either as a tag but I generally say `line` because it is simpler but `polyline` seems to have general acceptance as the more technical term.

Answer (score 0):

Line seems too ambiguous. Maybe polyline would be better.